# Can a private IP address have their location passed to an SSP?

Tags: geolocation, ip-address, ads

I have an app with ad inventory under an SSP. Is my app able to send a person's location data to the SSP if they are under a private IP address? Or if this occurs on desktop with my website?

Since the majority of IP addresses are private, does this mean ad exchanges (or DSPs, networks, etc) are blind to the majority of these people's locations?

Comment: no, the majority of IPs are NOT private. there's only 3 blocks of "private" ip addresses, and they're a small fraction of the entire ipv4 address space. but a growing majority of IP-enabled devices are USING the same blocks of private addresses.

Comment: I read a study that 70% of IP addresses are private. Did they mean 70% of activity is on private addresses? Also, can one's location be found on a private IP address?

Comment: private ip block are 10/8, 172.16/12, 192.168/16. that's a total of 17,891,238 IPs, out of a space of 4 billion = 0.417%

Comment: Since many people can be active on a single private IP block (tell me if I'm wrong here - can't an entire company be assigned to one?), then is it possible that there are more people on private IP addresses even though there are far far fewer blocks? I'm trying to understand how this study found 70% of measurements in their geo-location database to be from private IP addresses. (study: "Geolocating IP Addresses in Cellular Data Networks)